# Yii x-editable on CGridView: not stopping screen update when success returns error

Tags: json, yii-extensions, x-editable, cgridview

When json response sends `response.success == false`, I can see the console log showing me the error, but x-editable seems that doesn't catch the `return`, and the value in the screen is changed to the new one I had introduced, although it has not been really saved. Is there something wrong?

Here is piece of the CGridView code I use:

```
'class' => 'editable.EditableColumn',
'editable' => array(
  'model' => $model,
  'params' => array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken),
  'url' => $this->createUrl('user/update'),
  'success' => 'js: function(response, newValue) {
    if(!response.success) 
      console.log(response.msg);
      return response.msg;
    }',
  'options' => array(
    'ajaxOptions' => array('dataType' => 'json')
  ),
)
```

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, I have been working on that, and I have found which is the problem. It seems that the javascript **function** I put on success is not working properly.

The `if` statement is catching correctly the response, but the return value is not being sended correctly. I explain: if I put a literal like that: `return "test return";` the value is returned correctly, but if I put `return response.msg;` nothing is sended.

Of course, `response.msg` is not empty and contains the String message correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have been working on that and I found my stupid mistake... I was returning msg as array and I had to do this:

```
return response.msg[index];
```

Where `index` is where the message is stored.

It was really embarrassing losing time with that...